# Procedimiento almacenado no se ejecuta en php

Tags: php, mvc, stored-procedure, registro

Estoy creando una aplicación web MVC que debe registrar usuarios con Facebook. Todo bien hasta aquí, los datos que recibe de facebook llegan hasta la función que creé en la capa modelo en php, pero cuando llamo al procedimiento almacenado de la base de datos no se ejecuta como los otros que tengo en otras funciones y me extraña eso ya que tiene el mismo nombre que en la base de datos y hasta simplifiqué el código en MySQL para que pudiera recibir los datos aunque ya existieran pero nada funcionó, ¿alguien sabe a qué puede deberse esto?

La función en la que esta el procedimiento almacenado es la siguiente:

```
public function registroUsuarioFb($id,$nombre,$correo){
        $sqlquery = "CALL registroUsuarioFb(?,?,?)";

        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sqlquery);
        $statement->bindParam(1,$id);
        $statement->bindParam(2,$nombre);
        $statement->bindParam(3,$correo);

        if($statement->execute()){
            return "Exito " . $id .' ' . $nombre . ' ' . $correo . " usuario registrado";
        }
        else{
            return "Ocurrio un error " . $id .' ' . $nombre . ' ' . $correo . " usuario no registrado";
        }
    }
```

Siempre me esta retornando el error con los datos del usuario (es por eso que se que los datos llegan hasta esta capa).

Saludos a todos.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de php estás usando?

Comment: Estoy usando php 5.6.40

Comment: Te pregunto eso para saber si estabas usando una versión obsoleta de php. Esa versión 5.6 le dejaron de dar soporte el 2018. Podrías agregar el error que te muestra ?

Comment: Oh pero el detalle es que no es un error en sí mismo, mas bien es algo que simplemente no me quiere funcionar, ya que también uso ajax, y pues al final en el sitio me retorna el else que esta arriba en el código, donde dice usuario no registrado.

Comment: Agrega el error ahí **temporalmente** para depurar: `return "Ocurrio un error " . $id .' ' . $nombre . ' ' . $correo . " usuario no registrado\n ERROR: ".implode(" ",$this->conn->errorInfo());` Así te dirá cuál es el fallo, puede ser por clave duplicada u otro.

Comment: Ok gracias amigo, aunque me esta retornando "ERROR: 00000".

Comment: Lo que parece es que tu conexión ahí no es válida... somete la ejecución a un `if ($this->conn) {  //lanzar consulta } else { return "Conexión no válida"; } ` si pasa esa prueba quizá tengas la notificación de errores apagada

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿tu SP retorna algo? Parece que `0000` significa que todo está OK, que no hay error. Creo que el problema es el `if($statement->execute()){` para resolverlo hay que saber si tu procedure retorna algo o no.

Comment: Probaste tu procedimiento almacenado? porque puede que tengas error de sintaxis.

Comment: Pues si hay conexion a la base de datos, asi que no se que podria ser. Y mi SP no retorna algo, simplemente recibe los datos y los inserta en la tabla usuarios.

Comment: Y si ya probe mi procedimiento almacenado y si funciona todo bien

Comment: Ummm parece que las SP [retornan varios resultset](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call). Sería interesante poner el código así: `$statement->execute();  $data = $statement->fetchAll(); var_dump($data);` y/o verificar al mismo `$statement`  con `var_dump($statement);`

Answer (score 0):

Reproduciendo tu problema, pude resolverlo del siguiente modo:

1. Dado que dentro de la SP se ejecuta una consulta del tipo `INSERT` y ésta no devuelve nada, se puede verificar con [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php)si hubo filas insertadas.
2. Dado que al ser una SP dentro de la cual (al perecer) no se controlan los posibles duplicados u otros errores, y aunque se controlen no hay forma de saber el resultado porque no devuelve nada, implementaremos el código dentro de un bloque `try ... catch` como única posilibad de control de errores para este caso. En mi prueba intenté a propósito una inserción que generase un error del tipo *Duplicate key*, pero era imposible controlarlo mediante la verificación de `$statement`, porque éste realmente no fallaba, es decir, la llamada a la SP era exitosa, sólo que el resultado dentro de ella no lo era. Por lo tanto hay que controlarlo con `catch`.<sup>1</sup>

El código quedaría así:

```
public function registroUsuarioFb($id,$nombre,$correo)
{
    try 
    {
           $sqlquery = "CALL registroUsuarioFb(?,?,?)";

           $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sqlquery);
           $statement->bindParam(1,$id);
           $statement->bindParam(2,$nombre);
           $statement->bindParam(3,$correo);
           $statement->execute();
           if($statement->rowCount()>0)
           {
                return "Exito $id $nombre $correo usuario registrado";
           }
           else
           {
                return "0 filas insertadas $id $nombre $correo";
           }

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "Ocurrió un error en la SP. Código de error: {$statement->errorInfo()[1]}";
    }
}
```

De ese modo me ha funcionado.

### Notas

1. Convendría quizá controlar errores dentro de la SP y hacer que esta devuelva un estado o código de error, el cual pueda recuperarse para verificar lo que haya ocurrido.